# BLE connection interval

Tags: bluetooth

From BT snoop log below, found BLE central device and peripheral device got connected after a few loops of negotiation about
connection parameters, include connection interval, connection latency and supervisor timeout etc.

As found in bt snoop log, the connection interval will be set to 1 second, my question is:
Why not found the connection between them disappear 1 second later after they connected? 
What’s the real meaning of connection interval?

Answer (score 1):

As you know BLE has a pillar that is to be low energy consumption.
The main rule is turn on the radio as little as possible and turn off the radio as soon as possibile.
When a connection is established the radio signal isn't always active even when a peer want to transmit. The transmission phase has the radio turns on and off more times.
The connection interval is the time between two connection event and inside each connection event there is packets transmission.
Suppose the peer wants to transmitt 10 packets : the radio signal is on for packets transmission (max 6 packets) then turned off for a time that is the connection interval ... now 6 packets are transmitted. After connection interval, the radio is turned on to transmit tha last 4 packets and so on.
The connection interval can be from 7.5 ms and 4 s and it depends on both peers.
Of course, lesser connection interval means high baud rate transmission but more power consumption and vice versa.

Paolo.

Comment: Thank you Paolo,
If connection event interval always enabled after BLE connection established? If we can disable it when we need quick response from the other side? Or if BLE device enter into sniff or park mode like BR/EDR when there's no data transition?

Comment: Of course the radio signal starts only when peer wants to transmit data otherwise it's off. However, when peer starts to send data, the radio signal isn't always on but there is the mechanism I explained above so the connection interval takes place. You can't set it to 0, from standard the minimum value is 7.5 ms but consider that it depends on the other peer. For example, the smartphone doesn't support the minimum 7.5 ms ... the minimum value is tipically 30 ms AFAIK.

Comment: So it's very simple for BLE compare with BR/EDR, after BLE connected,both will wake up in connection interval time to do transmission, and they won't enter into hold or park mode if no data transition for a long time, am I right? Thank you, pp.

Comment: A BLE device stays in sleep mode most of time with radio signal off. Only when it needs to transmit data it turn on the radio signal and starts to transmit but considering the connection interval (so it turn off the radio even during transmission). After transmission complete it return in sleep.

Comment: Hi, pp, during connection event, if both ble device will sleep when no data to transmit? Or they would go to sleep only after connection event finished even no data for transmitting? Thank you.

Comment: they go to sleep every "connection interval"

Answer (score 1):

[image]

BLE is a radio communication protocol that work in the 2.4GHz spectrum.

If you measure the radio current on a CRO, while it is in a connection, you will get a graph something similar to shown above. 
The peaks indicate that radio is turned ON. Between the peaks the device is sleeping to save power.

To put it simply, connection interval is the time interval between the peaks.
Meaning it is the time for which the device sleeps after sending a packet and then wakes up to send a packet again.

This timing is synchronized between the two communication devices. It is like two people agreeing to meet at a particular time and place.